# Is there a way to state the fundamental theorem of Galois theory in a categorical sense?

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory, galois-connections

I will state the fundamental theorem of Galois theory to make things clear. Let $F/K$ be a finite dimensional Galois extension. Let $A$ be the set of all intermediate fields of $F/K$, and let $B$ be the set of all subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}_KF$. Let $f^*:A\to B$ be the function defined by $f^*(E)=\operatorname{Aut}_EF$. Define the function $f_*:B\to A$ by letting $f_*(H)$ be the fixed field of $H$. Then the fundamental theorem of Galois theory says that:
(1) $M\subseteq N$ implies $f^*(M)\geq f^*(N)$, and $I\geq J$ implies $f_*(I)\subseteq f_*(J)$;
(2) $f^*f_*$ and $f_*f^*$ are the identity functions;
(3) That $M\subseteq N$ is a Galois extension implies $f^*(M)\trianglerighteq f^*(N)$, and $I\trianglerighteq J$ implies that $f_*(I)\subseteq f_*(J)$ is a Galois extension.

We can rephrase (1) and (2) by saying that $(f^*,f_*)$ is a pair of category isomorphisms (viewing the preordered sets $(A,\subseteq)$ and $(B,\geq)$ as categories). But how can we rephrase (1) - (3) simultaneously? I do not know how to view structures such as $(B,\trianglerighteq,\geq)$ as categories.

Comment: Yes, most definitely: http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Galois+Theories

Comment: See also the section mentioning categories[here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/gt/gt.pdf).

Comment: @Ittay I skimmed the article, but I don't quite see how it answers my question. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @rschwieb Is it section 8.1? But I still don't know how to view "doubly ordered" sets $(A,\text{"is a Galois subfield of"}, \subseteq)$ and $(B,\trianglerighteq,\geq)$ as categories.

Comment: @zxcv Maybe someone can find a way to shoehorn that third point into a categorical context, but I'm not sure I see that it is worthwhile. The big thing is that $f_\ast$ and $f^\ast$ are adjoint functors between those two posets, which restrict to an isomorphism when the extension is "nice," and you've already captured that categorically.  The rest feels to me like a statement about restricting to subcategories.